# sort array of file's names by value of first row in files

Tags: perl, bash, sorting

I have array INPUTFILES with n files

```
INPUTFILES=( file_0 ... files_n-1 )
```

And i need to sort them in the array order by first row in files.

Files look like this:

```
2012.09.20 17:10
2012.11.21 00:10
2012.12.22 15:10
2012.12.23 15:10
```

I have already function to compare 2 files:

```
IsSooner () {
ONEFIRST=$( head -1 "${1}" ) 
ONELAST=$( tail -1 "${1}" )
TWOFIRST=$( head -1 "${2}" ) 
TWOLAST=$( tail -1 "${2}" )

TIMEFORMAT='Y.%m.%d %H:%M:'

perl <<EOF
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;

open STDERR, "> /dev/null";

my @dates1 = ("${ONEFIRST}","${ONELAST}");
my @range1 = map Time::Piece->strptime("\$_", "${TIMEFORMAT}"), @dates1;

my @dates2 = ("${TWOFIRST}","${TWOLAST}");
my @range2 = map Time::Piece->strptime("\$_", "${TIMEFORMAT}"), @dates2;

if ( \$range1[0] < \$range2[0] ) {
  exit 0;
}

exit 1;
EOF

[ $? -eq 0 ] && {
  return 0
}

return 1  
}
```

Earlier will be first date in the file, the smaller index in the array will have.

Solution in BASH if preferable.

**UPDATE**
I don't know format of date in advance. I just know it will be in strftime(3c) format.

Comment: If i understand, you want to replace perl with shell?

Comment: Nope. The perl fragment is necessary. I just need to re-arrange the order in the array INPUTFILES. I just add compare function, because to set order of the set, you have to have comparable items.

Comment: Why is the perl necessary? It seems to be doing more work than necessary (why read the last line of each file?), and doesn't do anything except compare two first lines together. I say, go with user1215106's answer.

Comment: @tuxuday Yes, i am looking for right solution. An first idea was to use associated array, but i am not sure.

Comment: @chepner It is necessary, because i dont have fixed date format (In example is). And bash/nawk doesn't have strptime() equivalent.

Comment: @chepner It does litle more work than i need, because i quickly re-edited from another function and perl is not my cup of tea :). But it does its job well.

Comment: @Rob, you don't really need `strptime` here at all, as those strings can be compared naturally without parsing.

Comment: @Oleg V. Volkov Check the update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In simple loop read first line of each file and save this information to hash, having first row data a hash key and the file name a hash value.

   ```
   my @inpufiles = ...;
   my %hash;
   foreach (@inputfiles) {
     open(my $fh, $_) or die $!;
     $hash{<$fh>} = $_;
     close $fh;
   }
   ```
2. Sort the hash by the keys and print all values of sorted hash.

   ```
   foreach (sort (keys(%hash))) {
     print "$hash{$_}\n";
   }
   ```

   If you don't want to print it, just store it back to the array, then do just

   ```
   @inputfiles = map {$hash{$_}} sort (keys(%hash));
   ```

Good luck!

---

**[UPDATE]**

To follow the update in your question I suggest you to store values to hash using:

```
$hash{Time::Piece->strptime(<$fh>, $timeformat)->epoch} = $_;
```

Comment: This is sorted lexically, right. If yes, this doesn't help me.That's because i am using Time::Piece objects to compare each other.

Comment: @Rob - Other user(s) already wrote(s) comment(s) below your question, where is noted that **you do not need** to sort data by custom sort, because your data are in "YYYY.MM.DD HH:NN" format and "lexically" sort is the right solution for this format...

Comment: Just change `$hash{<$fh>} = $_` to whatever you need to normalize values. I suggest normalizing to seconds since epoch.

Comment: This solution will drop input files if the first row is the same. Could be a real problem since timestamps are usually not unique.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [Schwartzian Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) to sort the list of files:

```
my @inputfiles =
  map  { $_->[0] }
  sort { $a->[1] cmp $b->[1] }
  map  { [ $_, do { open my($f), $_; chomp(my $time = <$f>); $time } ] }
    qw/file_0 file_1 file_2/;
```

This can actually be written as a small bash pipeline, so you don't even need perl:

```
INPUTFILES=($(grep -m1 '' file_0 file_1 file_2 | sort -t: -k2 | cut -d: -f1))
```